# ListView onScroll being called multiple times

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-asynctask, onscrolllistener

I know that this question has been asked before but I think I am really close to my solution and therefore I wish to do this way.
I am using a ListView and populating it with some data. Now, I am trying to populate it with some more data when the user reaches the bottom. This should continue as long as there are less than 100 items in the ListView. But the code below add all the data at once when I scroll it to the bottom for the first time. I guess there are tens of calls to my async method that loads more data.

```
@Override
                    public void onScroll(AbsListView absListView, int firstVisibleItem,
                                         int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
                        scrollTask myscrolltask = new scrollTask();
                        int lastVisibleIndex = absListView.getLastVisiblePosition();

                        if(lastVisibleIndex != totalItemCount - 1)
                        {
                            System.out.print("lastVisibleIndex "+lastVisibleIndex);
                            System.out.print("totalItemCount-1 " + (totalItemCount-1));
                            myscrolltask.cancel(true);
                            return;
                        }
                        if(moreNewsAvailable == 0)
                            return;
                        if(totalItemCount > 75)
                            return;


                        Log.v("Total Item Count", String.valueOf(totalItemCount));
                        int lastItem = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount;
                        if(lastItem == totalItemCount && totalItemCount<=75 && moreNewsAvailable==1 && lastVisibleIndex != -1 && totalItemCount!=0)  //Means that you have reached the bottom
                        {
                            Log.v("LastVisibleItemPosition", String.valueOf(lastVisibleIndex));

                            setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);

                            myscrolltask.execute("");
                        }
                    }
```

Is there anyway around? How can I make sure that only one call to the async is made when reaching bottom?

Answer (score 1):

create a Boolean variable and set that variable to true in task execution and again set that Boolean to true on task completion.
Check if task is in progress than dont execute on scroll method.

```
if(!isLoading){
        if(lastVisibleIndex != totalItemCount - 1)
        {
            System.out.print("lastVisibleIndex "+lastVisibleIndex);
            System.out.print("totalItemCount-1 " + (totalItemCount-1));
            myscrolltask.cancel(true);
            return;
        }
        if(moreNewsAvailable == 0)
            return;
        if(totalItemCount > 75)
            return;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks that helped. But now the List View scrolls to the top every time new items are added. What can I do to help it?

Comment: change the related list attached with listview and call notifydatasetchanged() at the completion of task

Comment: note that you are not setting the adapter in task. you only have to notify in task. set the adapter just after initializing the list.

Comment: list view resets the scroll position if adapter was removed or reset .

Comment: So if I change values in the arrays that are passed into the adapter, I don't need to reset the adapter? I only need to notify? Is that correct?